# How to get the class name of a window with C

Tags: c, winapi

Objective: Retrieve the class name of the current foreground window with plain C.

I have the following code to retrieve the class name:

```
PWSTR win_class = NULL; 

GetClassNameW(hwnd,&win_class,MAX_PATH);

if(win_class != NULL)
   free(win_class);
```

I am getting the following warnings:

> warning C4047: 'function': 'LPWSTR' differs in levels of indirection
> from 'PWSTR *'
>  warning C4024: 'GetClassNameW': different types
> for formal and actual parameter 2

I have two questions: How to solve those warnings, and how should I create an `if` condition to validate the result of the function `GetClassName` and set the value of `win_class` to "NOT FOUND" in case that the function does not find the class name?

Comment: The [man page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassnamew) shows, `int GetClassNameW(HWND hWnd, LPWSTR lpClassName, int nMaxCount)` needs a `LPWSTR` argument to somewhere to store the class name. *"If the function succeeds, the return value is the number of characters copied to the buffer, not including the terminating null character."* Also, I don't think `free(win_class);` is the way to finish with an object. How to you know it was obtained by `malloc`? Is this an [XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `GetClassNameW()`, you are passing a `PWSTR*` (`wchar_t**`) where a `LPWSTR` (`wchar_t*`) is expected. That is what the compiler is complaining about.

`GetClassName()` requires you to pre-allocate a character buffer and pass in a pointer to it, along with the buffer size.  The function will not allocate a buffer and return a pointer back to you, like you are expecting.  It will merely fill in your provided buffer as needed.

Try something more like this:

```c
WCHAR win_class[256] = {0};
int win_class_len = 0;

HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
if (!hwnd)
{
    // error handling as needed...
    lstrcpyW(win_class, L"WINDOW NOT FOUND");
    win_class_len = lstrlenW(win_class);
}
else
{
    win_class_len = GetClassNameW(hwnd, win_class, 256);
    if (win_class_len == 0)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        // error handling as needed...
        lstrcpyW(win_class, L"CLASS NOT FOUND");
        win_class_len = lstrlenW(win_class);
    }
}

// use win_class as needed, up to win_class_len characters...
```

Comment: Hi @Remy, can I use std::wstring(win_class); to return wstring text? My code always reports a memory leak.

Comment: Yes, `std::wstring(win_class)` will work just fine, provided `win_class` is null terminated properly (otherwise, pass in the length as another parameter to `std::wstring`). There is no memory leak in this code, your leak is elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The `GetClassNameW()` function does *not* allocate the memory needed for the returned class name - *you* have to do that (or simply provide automatic storage).

To check for success, simply test the return value of the function: if it succeeds, that will be the length of the class name string (in characters); if it fails, the value will be zero.

Here's a short, runnable program that gets the class name for the console window:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    wchar_t win_class[_MAX_PATH];
    int status = GetClassNameW(hwnd, win_class, _MAX_PATH);
    if (!status) wcscpy(win_class, L"NOT FOUND");
    printf("%ls\n", win_class);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great MWE answer. Should be a blueprint for most of the questions.

Answer (score 0):

`TCHAR` is the universal char type working for Unicode and ANSI. `GetClassName` is the corresponding function replaced with `GetClassNameA` or `GetClassNameW`. If you need static string use `TEXT()` macro like `TCHAR * s = TEXT("abc");`

```
TCHAR win_class[MAX_PATH];
int res = GetClassName( hwnd, win_class, MAX_PATH );
if ( res > 0 )
   // success
```

Your error is that `win_class` was unallocated (NULL) string pointer. `GetClassName` needs valid memory address of buffer.

Comment: Tks @i486. I am corious about your answer. What is the difference between Getclassname, GetclassnameW and GetclassnameA?. There is a special rule to use it with C language?.

Comment: @sergioMoreno `GetClassNameW()` works with Unicode `wchar_t` strings, `GetClassNameA()` with ANSI `char` strings. `TCHAR` is a preprocessor macro that maps to `wchar_t` or `char`, and `GetClassName()` is a preprocessor macro that maps to `GetClassNameW` or `GetClassNameA`, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not, respectively.  Same for all other Win32 API `A`/`W` types/functions.

Comment: @i486 "*Your error is that `win_class` was unallocated (NULL) string pointer*" - that is not why the compiler failed. Yes, that was wrong, but the failure was because the OP's code was passing a `PWSTR*` (`wchar_t**`) where a `PWSTR` (`wchar_t*`) was expected.

Comment: @sergioMoreno Using `GetClassName` is the "normal way" - even MSDN describes functions without A/W suffix. With `TCHAR` / `LPTSTR` types and `TEXT()` for string constants you have portable code. You can open `winuser.h` and other header files and see how they define `GetClassName`, `TCHAR`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you function succseed. To do so, print the return value of the function.

Failiure will be presented by the value 0.